# How to disable the "do not close application" option in MSI Installshield restart manager dialog

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, restartmanager

How to disable the "**Do not close application**" option in MSI installshield restart manager dialog so that the user is forced to select the first option - 
automatically close and attempt to restart applications so that the user does not have to accidentally require reboot during installation. Disabling the dialog completely shows the "**FilesInUse**" dialog which when Ignored caused the Restart Manager to appear again. So the most elegant option might be to disable the second option altogether.

I am using installshield 2015 SP2.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest a little hack, even if I can't test it in Installshield right now.

I believe this dialog has a **`RadioButtonGroup`** control element which sets the property **`RestartManagerOption`**. The visibility and enabled / disabled status for such a control element is set in the **Attributes column** of the [**Control Table**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368044(v=vs.85).aspx).

You could try to set the **Attributes value** to **`1`** for "`Visible, but disabled`". Here are [the flags or control attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/control-attributes) for reference.
I suppose you could hide the whole control, but I would keep it visible. Just my preference.

I just might try to make this change to a compiled MSI using Orca or Installshield itself to "hotfix" an MSI - just to see if it actually works the way you want it. Otherwise I think there should be a property in the property view for that dialog that says something along the lines of **`"Enabled"`**. Set it to **`False`**.

[image: Orca, hotfixing the Control Table. Fire in the hole!]

---

***Some Links***:

- [Windows Installer-Avoid FileinUse dialog box when Installing a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917062/windows-installer-avoid-fileinuse-dialog-box-when-installing-a-package) (a write-up of issues relating to the RestartManager and the wish to suppress files in use dialogs)