# Work around to prevent windows msi installer from terminating the process it updates

Tags: windows-installer

In windows I am updating an application using MSI package while the application is running.  I understand the MSI installer has to terminate the running application, then perform installation.  I want to keep one of the running process in the app running until the installation finishes, how can I work around to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at properties MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL,
MSIDISABLERMRESTART and MSIRMSHUTDOWN.  Read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/disableautomaticapplicationshutdown

Comment: What kind of process is this? Is it crucially important? I have this previous answer on [RestartManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50935008/129130). And there is this: [How do I add support for Windows Restart Manager to my application?](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-vista-restart-manager.html) ([Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com)). The overall idea of RestartManager is basically to prefer restarting applications rather than restarting the OS. To that end the application needs to know: "how to shut down safely and restart itself".

Comment: This process is spawned by the app when the app receives a command from a management server to update itself. Management server uploads the installation package, and this process will run the installation package, and monitor the installation and reports the status to the management server. That is why I'd like to keep this process running until the installation finishes.