# Update a running application with .msi

Tags: installation, windows-installer, auto-update

I have a desktop application that automatically checks for updates on every start and automatically installs the update silently if one is available. I am using an `.exe` setup created with NSIS for that and do it with the following steps:

1. While the app is running I move all application files to the temp folder
2. I download and silently run the `setup.exe` file
3. I restart my application and do a cleanup of the temp folder

This allows me to update the application while it is running. I would like to do something similar with a Wix `.msi` installer, but I am not sure if and how it is possible. I know there is a silent flag, but I believe `.msi` keeps track of all the files it has installed so will this work anyway? Can I just do the same thing with an `.msi` installer or how would one generally handle this? Is it maybe even possible to put all this logic directly inside the installer?

Comment: [Maybe have a quick read here on "Restart Manager"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50935008/129130) - a bit down the page. Essentially your application should shut itself down gracefully and be capable of restarting itself. The whole idea is to restart applications and not have to reboot / restart Windows itself. You are not on a terminal server - are you? (many user logins possible).

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that.

Comment: Maybe this Advanced Installer article can help you get a scope of things? There is a lot of text in that link above, this one is terser: [How do I add support for Windows Restart Manager to my application?](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-vista-restart-manager.html) - it is both technical and practical - which is nice to "hit the ground running".