Msiexec.exe /norestart parameter not working
I have a problem starting a process to execute installation of specified installer in quiet mode with no restart.
This is my code:
public int InstallUpdate(string installerLocation)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
    p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i " + installerLocation + " /qn /norestart";
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    return p.ExitCode;
}

This is called from a dll loaded in AutoCAD (plugin). It used to work perfectly fine up until recently, but now when installation is finished AutoCAD shuts down, and the /norestart is ignored.
The idea is to execute installer from AutoCAD quietly and inform the user if installation is successful and that AutoCAD needs to be restarted in order for the changes to take place. But now, right after the successful installation AutoCAD is shut down, so it looks like it crashes.
These are few last messages from installation log:

MSI (s) (14:68) [11:18:20:810]: RESTART MANAGER: Will attempt to shut down and restart applications in no UI modes.
MSI (s) (14:68) [11:18:20:810]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error
MSI (s) (14:68) [11:18:20:810]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT Message FROM Error WHERE Error = 1607
MSI (s) (14:68) [11:18:20:810]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error
MSI (s) (14:68) [11:18:20:810]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT Message FROM Error WHERE Error = 1607
MSI (s) (14:68) [11:18:20:827]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText
MSI (c) (E8:DC) [11:18:20:812]: RESTART MANAGER: Session opened.
MSI (s) (14:68) [11:18:20:951]: RESTART MANAGER: Successfully shut down all applications in the service's session that held files in use.
MSI (c) (E8:DC) [11:18:20:952]: RESTART MANAGER: Successfully shut down all applications that held files in use.

When it was working OK, RESTART MANAGER messages didn't appear.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

/norestart: "The installer never restarts the computer after the installation." - you haven't mentioned the computer restarting so it seems to be working fine.

Have you tried /qn+ ? That would give you a messagebox at the end, where you might determine what goes wrong.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right. I thought that /norestart also refers to not restarting the application that holds files-in-use.  This post has a lot of useful information about Restart Manager: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50935008/8790321

@PalleDue yes I tried multiple combinations using parameters for msiexec, but without luck. I got it to work without restarting AutoCAD by setting MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL property to Disable, but then the installation process became terribly slow. So I decided not to go with that.
